# How to create a material data table with form functionality to save records

Tags: typescript, angular-material2, angular5

Getting lot of errors

> Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined ("
>   
>               ]*matRowDef="columns:displayedColumns" >

To add rows in the table dynamically

```
<button (click)="addABunch(3)">Add 3</button>
```

To create the user with is name and mobile number

```
<mat-table #table>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="Username">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Drug Name</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell >
                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                    <input class="form-control" matInput 
                                   formControlName="Name">
                  </mat-form-field>
            </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Mobile">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Drug Name</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell>
                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                    <input class="form-control" matInput 
                         formControlName="Mobile">
                  </mat-form-field>
            </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
            <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns">
                        </mat-header-row>
            <mat-row *matRowDef="columns: displayedColumns"></mat-row>
                 </mat-table>
```

And Typescript code is

```
 displayedColumns = [' Name', 'Mobile'];

addABunch(n: number) {
  for (let x = 0; x < n; x++) {
    this.items.push({ value: ++this.max });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that's an invalid `matRowDef` statement. Use this instead

`<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>`